# AS3 Remove characters after a word in a string

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs5

AS3 | Adove Air 3.5 | Flash CS6

I have html pulled from a source online put into a String that I'm taking apart piece by piece to build an XML file based off of the information I pulled.  I need to search the whole String to remove characters following "info" up until the character "&".  There are multiple instances of this throughout the string, so I thought it would be best to use a RegExp.  Other suggestions are welcomed.

```
//code from the website put into a full string
var fullString = new String(urlLoader.data);

//search string to find <info> and remove characters AFTER it up until the character '&'
var stringPlusFive:RegExp = /<info>1A2E589EIM&/g;

//should only remove '1A2E589EIM' leaving '<info>&'
fullString = fullString.replace(stringPlusFive,"");
```

The problem I'm having trouble figuring out is the "1A2E589EIM" is not consistent.  They are random numbers and characters, and possibly length, so I can't really use what I have written above.  It will always lead up to a "&".

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the regexp would be more like

```
//search string to find <info> and remove characters AFTER it up until the character '&'
var stringPlusFive:RegExp = /<info>\w+&/g;

//should only remove '1A2E589EIM' leaving '<info>&'
fullString = fullString.replace(stringPlusFive,"<info>&");
```

now, if you are going to parse your string to XML, you could wait until you have your XML structure and just remove the info string from 'info' nodes

```
//code from the website put into a full string
var fullString = new String(urlLoader.data);

//parse to XML
var xml:XML = XML(fullString),
    index:int, text:string;

for each(var info:XML in xml.descendants('info')){
  text = info.*[0].text();
  index = text.indexOf('&');
  if(index != -1){
    info.*[0] = text.substr(index);
  }
}
```

I'm not sure about the affectation to *[0] but it should be something like that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah the problem is getting into XML format before I can start doing XML commands.  The /<info>\w+&/g; worked though.  Thanks for that!